# Cross-compiling for AArch64 and OpenCL on Linux

Tags: android, linux, opencl, arm64

When I tried to cross-compile for AArch64 and OpenCL on Linux using NDK-r14b, I encountered the following errors:

```
/home/ferey/Android/android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: /home/ferey/work/jpeg/opencl/lib64/libm.so: don't know how to handle section `.relr.dyn' [0x      13]
/home/ferey/Android/android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/ferey/work/jpeg/opencl/lib64/libm.so when searching for -lm
/home/ferey/Android/android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/ferey/work/jpeg/opencl/lib64/libc.so when searching for -lc
/home/ferey/Android/android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: libcutils.so, needed by /home/ferey/work/jpeg/opencl/lib64/libOpenCL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/ferey/Android/android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: libc++.so, needed by /home/ferey/work/jpeg/opencl/lib64/libOpenCL.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/ferey/Android/android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r14b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: ld-android.so, needed by /home/ferey/work/jpeg/opencl/lib64/libdl.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/ferey/work/jpeg/opencl/lib64/libOpenCL.so: undefined reference to `property_get'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The compilation command I used was:

```
./aarch64-linux-android-g++ --sysroot=/home/ferey/Android/android-ndk-r14b-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r14b/platforms/android-22/arch-arm64 -I/home/ferey/work/jpeg/opencl/include -L/home/ferey/work/jpeg/opencl/lib64 /home/ferey/work/jpeg/opencl/main.c -pie -fPIC -o /home/ferey/work/jpeg/opencl/main -lOpenCL
```

The OpenCL related .so files I used were extracted from the phone, including the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYqeR.png)
My phone is a Pixel 4, with the operating system Android 13.

I tried replacing the libc.so library, but it still couldn't pass the compilation.

Comment: It seems that your toolchain dir is not included. Make sure those core library (ex: libcutil.so, libc++.so, ...) is include by `-L`

Comment: Why are you using r14b?